# Is there any alternative of Volley used in android to call REST services for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking for any alternative of volley in xamarin forms to communicate with REST services.
I am currently using HttpClient to communicate with REST services.
But now i am looking for some alternative which gives me advantages of volley.
I searched but nothing found .
If anybody knows please comment.

Answer (score 3):

I know about [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) This is similar to Retrofit which is in the native android

Comment: Thank you qubuss...let me check

Comment: Seconded. Refit is extremely useful.

Comment: So is better use Refit or use HttpClient and BaseClass and interfaces?

Comment: In my work I'm using HttpClient  but I can change to Refit and I don't know what is better and why

Comment: Use any library you feel comfortable with, just bear in mind that when putting your HTTP code in the shared library it becomes more difficult to deal with situations like No Internet, queue's etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your Xamarin.Android Project and can create aa DependencyService in your Xamarin forms project to use and access Volley.

https://github.com/CSharpCross/Volley-For-Xamarin-Android

Or,

https://github.com/royd/Xamarin.Android.Volley